# Spring Boot ExceptionHandler is returning XML and not JSON

Tags: json, xml, spring, spring-boot, exception

My whole API generates JSON without any problem, but as soon as an exception is thrown, the controller decides to stringy the object to XML... why?

My controller looks like this:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller{
@ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler({ IllegalArgumentException.class, MissingServletRequestParameterException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Map<String, Object> invalid(Exception ex){
        return new ObjectResponseBuilder().add("message", ex.getMessage()).get();
    }
}
```

However this is the response I get:

```xml
<Map>
    <message>Required request parameter 'min' for method parameter type Long is not present</message>
</Map>
```

I'm making the request directly from the browser, so no header is set... just like for all the others endpoints (that are returning JSON instead)

Comment: You can return `ResponseEntity` class with the header `Content-Type=application/json` or use builde `ResponseEntity.badRequest().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: So i must specify this every single time? Are there ways to do it like on the configuration?